# Linq to SQL Associated Table Not Accessible

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am reworking an application that had previously working code in it.  By necessity, I'm moving several commonly-used bits to a separate project.  One of those is a Linq to SQL Model.

I have all references resolved and all namespaces corrected so that everything compiles correctly EXCEPT for a couple of areas where the code is using a mapping association to access a different table.

So for example,

```
    Template t = db.Templates.FirstOrDefault( f => f.TemplateId == templateId );
    List<Item> templateList = new List<Item>( );
    foreach ( var r in globalItems )
    {
        if (t.TemplateChildren.FirstOrDefault( f => f.ItemId == r.ItemId ) != null )
            // do some stuff...
    }
```

In this instance, I cannot access t..TemplateChildren.  The compiler tells me it is **inaccessible due to its protection level.**

Taking a look at the Linq to SQL Designer code, I find the problem:

```
        [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AssociationAttribute(Name="Template_TemplateChildren", Storage="_TemplateChildren", ThisKey="TemplateId", OtherKey="TemplateId")]
    internal EntitySet<TemplateChildren> TemplateChildren
    {
        get
        {
            return this._TemplateChildren;
        }
        set
        {
            this._TemplateChildren.Assign(value);
        }
    }
```

Notice that the EntitySet has been decorated with "internal".  If I change this to "public", the code compiles fine.  But of course, any change to the model will break it again because this is tool-generated code.

This worked when the model was in the same project as the code thatt's calling it, and I've checked and double-checked that everything is set to PUBLIC in the model itself, yet the code generator insists on making this mapping INTERNAL.

Anyone have thoughts as to why this works that way, or how I can trick the code generator into making it PUBLIC?

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question:

Open the model and click on the relationship arrow that's being problematic.  In the properties pane, expand either "Child Property" or "Parent Property" as needed and change the Access modifier.